# Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

My question is the following;

**Q: Prove that if we move straight down in Pascal’s Triangle (visiting every other row), then the numbers we see are increasing.**

Found an answer but that doesn't count as a proof I think. By the way I couldn't write down what I found because I don't know LaTeX forgive me for that.

So, could you help me please?

Comment: [Here is a $\LaTeX$ tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You could try what you know without LaTeX. As long as it's somewhat readable, I'm sure someone would be willing to edit it into LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you're comparing $\binom{n}{k}$ and $\binom{n+2}{k+1}$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{n+2}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(n-k+1)(k+1)} >1,
\end{align*}
and so, you're done.

Comment: Why this equation is always greater than one?

Comment: $n+1 \geq n-k+1$ always, and $n+2 \geq k+1$ as long as $k < n$. If $k=n$, then the inequality above holds anyway.